# What does wxMessageBox return in python?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm looking for simple wx.MessageBox return value example. I've seen some basic examples and they look a lot like this. So far I have:

```
dlg = wx.MessageBox( 'What do you choose?, 'Test Dialog', wx.YES_NO | wx.NO_DEFAULT | wx.ICON_QUESTION )
if dlg == wx.ID_YES:
    print 'You picked yes'
```

dlg seems to return 8 for No and 2 for yes. However wx.ID_YES = 2503 and wx.ID_NO = 5104

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7):

`wx.MessageBox` returns one of `wx.YES`, `wx.NO`, `wx.OK`, `wx.CANCEL`.

Use `wx.YES` instead of `wx.ID_YES`, `wx.NO` instead of `wx.ID_NO`:

```
>>> import wx
>>> wx.YES
2
>>> wx.NO
8
```

See [`::wxMessageBox`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_dialogfunctions.html#wxmessagebox)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
yesNobox = wx.MessageDialog(None,"What do you choose?",'Question',wx.YES_NO)
yesNoAnswer = yesNobox.ShowModal()
```

so you have your answer in the yesNoAnswer to see if its yes or no you can use this

```
yesNoAnswer == wx.ID_YES: 
yesNoAnswer == wx.ID_NO:
```